# Importing framework into existing project

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I'm trying to import Parse.com's framework into an existing project, but for some reason I can't access all the header files included in the framework. When I create a new project, I can access all the framework's objects, methods, and header files just fine. And if I add it to another existing project that I haven't done played around with too much, it also works fine.

What could I have done to my existing project to make it not import a framework correctly/not let me use all the headers?

I've been working on this project for a while and have added a number of other frameworks (MKStoreKit, SDWebImage) and messed with the app's settings, so I have no idea where to start with trying to track this issue down.

Thanks!

**Edit**

When I copy the folder to Dropbox, the framework works fully from that file as well... What could be going on here? What doesn't get carried over when you copy a project from one location to another?

Comment: how are you trying to import the headers.  When you expand the frameowrk in your project do you see any headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

odd problem.  here is a back to basics suggestion.  sorry if its seems obvious.

I would suggest to remove the framework from the project, then go to finder and make sure that there is no residual files or directories in the project folders.

Also, if you are using git, make sure there is no reference to exclude the files from your project directory in .gitignore

do a clean - shift, cmd K

Then go to the project info tab, then frameworks, then hit the + key to add a new framework, then choose other, then pick your parse framework.

that should work.

if not, do all that, then close and restart Xcode, then reopen your project and try again.

Answer (score 0):

For the headers to be available the framework has to be built to expose the public headers.  If you are building the framework yourself make sure you check build phases and specify the public headers

Comment: I'm not building it myself - I'm using Parse.com's framework.